# Safest way to pass data between forms in c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, multiple-forms, data-security

I'm trying to remember a lesson I was taught briefly in school about safely passing data between winforms.

My instructor called it *pipelining*, though I'm not sure if this is the correct term or merely his own name for it. He stated that his method was safer than the easiest way of publicizing the data so that everything can access it. He said it was safer because his method prevented access of the data from external programs or unrelated forms and processes, and he hailed it as good programming practice.

My foundation in programming was very weak at the time. I lacked a deeper understanding of what he told me, and was really just repeating his steps. Without any concepts to bond his teachings to, I easily forgot his method.

Now, I am better at what I do and I want to establish in a simple Q&A the **safest, most secure way to share data between winforms**. That is, a method that keeps the data safe and secure, and can go from Form A to Form B, or Forms B, C, D... etc as I designate it, but does *not* leak out in any way.

To specify, I'm looking to share data between forms in the same application. Maybe some day I'll try to share data between processes, but right now I only care about the forms.

To make a more specific example, I am trying to pass the simple strings of name `versionNumber` and `lastEditDate` from the `Main` form to an `About` form, the knowledge for this allowing me to have a bunch of static variables that I only have to change in one location of the code, that can be passed down to any form I desire. But I want a secure way to do this, just in case passing data between forms by defining globally is considered bad practice, or unsafe.

Comment: just to clarify you mean between two separate processes, right?  Not just two forms running on one application

Comment: First of all I think you're overthinking data security in the context of a Windows application.  If data is in memory anyone can get to it, you only really achieve data security through web applications.  Your question is a bit ambiguous because you refer to pipes which are used for interprocess communication but you say you want to share data between multiple "Winforms" forms which is not interprocess, it's just within your code.  Maybe you can clarify which you want to do.

Comment: The edits have been made that I hope clarify my situation. I also want this question to serve as a guide for future nooblets on a good *how* **and** *why* for any method of data-passing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the reasoning that you have given for just having a lot of public static data is not correct.  It is no more or less secure from malicious attempts of another processes to access the information.  It's in memory no matter what you do, so a malicious process (with sufficient privileges) *can* get at it no matter what, but they're likely to have a bit of a hard time of it no matter what as well.  If you have a malicious process/user with that level of permissions you've already lost the fight; they can already do whatever they want.

The problems with storing all of your data in public static fields is merely a matter of effective development, not of actual security.  When the data can be modified from anywhere in your entire program at any time it makes it extraordinary hard to understand what's going on in the program at any one point in time, it makes bugs *really* hard to track down as there could be problems almost anywhere in the code, it makes bringing in new developers to a project really hard because they can't just open up a class or two and understand them, they need to understand the *entire application* to be able to reason correctly about what's going on in any one part, due to the high level of coupling in your application.

You should strive to reduce coupling of various modules in your application by keeping the data more localized.  This allows a developer to look at a single module (whether that be a form, a user control, some worker class, etc.) and only need to understand that class in front of them without needing to understand every single point in the entire application that also touches the same variables.

You also need to be very concerned about threading issues when you're accessing public static variables from multiple threads, since you almost certainly are going to require multiple threads in a winform application.

Finally, if you're storing all of your data statically it means that you'll never be able to have multiple instances of your forms.  Most forms that you'll write, from a logical perspective, shouldn't *require* that there never be more than one of them in an application.  If their data is localized to just them there isn't any problem creating a second form.  If all of the data is static, then the forms will end up fighting with each other over that data.

As for how to accomplish this, the primary goal here should be to keep data scoped as narrowly as you are able to (which is something that you should generally strive for throughout all types of programming) without allowing variables to be accessible in places where they don't need to be accessed.

The case you've described is a fairly straightforward problem to solve.  If a form is creating another form that needs some data upon construction, if that data is *essential* to the use of that other form then just create parameters in the constructor for that data.  The form (or whatever else) creating it can then pass in that required data.  If the data isn't required, or it isn't required right at construction, then the other option is to have properties that allow the "owner" of that form to pass in the data that is needed.  Doing this isn't really any more complex than creating a public static field; it's simply creating a public non-static property.

Now that this data isn't static you know that, rather than being accessed from anywhere, that information is going to be provided from whoever is "owning" that particular instance of the form.  You're limiting the scope of where the data can be accessed to place that needs it, and the place that has it, rather than "everywhere".

Comment: Your answer is fantastic and is exactly the "why" I was looking for. However, would you be able to add some code at the bottom for a working example? For instance, you say what a constructor is and I'm too new to be able to translate the keywords you use into code on a page.

Comment: @JWarner112 There are *many* resources available that describe how to define the constructor for a type, how to add parameters to that constructor, and how to call the constructor of a given object.  I have faith that you'll be able to do the research/experimentation required to come up with those solutions on your own.

Comment: There certainly is enough information elsewhere to find this answer. The problem is the linearity of solving a problem oneself. In order to find the right answer, one must know *what* they don't understand and *how* they don't understand it. To put it simply, I don't know what a constructor is but I also don't know why I don't understand it. To have a misunderstanding an unknown number of levels deep is the real killer in all of this. For instance, inside an event handler method `aboutToolStripMenuItem_Click` I have the string `versionNumber` declared. However (continued)

Comment: the following lines `var myFormAbout = new formAbout(versionNumber);` gives me an error `"project1.formAbout" does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments`. And it's not that I can't look this up and solve it myself, it's that I have literally no idea where to begin to look. Believe me, I'm not lazy and I'm not stupid; If I know where to begin I look there, I don't like bothering other people this way. But when I'm lost so completely, that's where I need understanding and experienced folks like yourself to help me along. And I try to pave the way for other newcomers like me, as I go.

Comment: @JWarner112 So what is the error telling you?  You haven't defined a constructor that takes those parameters.  So define a constructor that takes those parameters.  If you don't know how to define a constructor, look up how to define a constructor.  That's a very specific, narrow, searchable task that will return lots of results that explain how you define a constructor that takes a parameter in C#.  Don't try to find a single resource that tells you everything you need to know.  Look up each of the individual pieces that you need to know one at a time, as you need them.

Comment: Yes. Thank you, this is exactly the direction I needed pointed in. Before, the vagueries apparent to me lead me to question whether I needed a new constructor or whether I was simply defining the parameter in error, or something. You've been extremely helpful and I'm sorry if my helplessness played on your nerves somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

I usually declare my variable in program.cs in your situation, and reach it from anywhere as Program.xxx. but you need a non public way of reaching a variable...

Ahhaaa, another way is as following. when you create a form from another form. Write an overloaded contructor for second form, and pass parameters to that contructor. like:

```
Form2 frm = new Form2(myParameter);
```

Comment: When I use your method, I write: `formAbout myFormAbout = new formAbout(versionNumber);`, `versionNumber` having been defined just above it. I get the error: `"<Project name>.formAbout" does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments.`. I do not understand this.

Comment: yep. because you have not define any constructor that takes 1 argument. now you need to go formAbout class and write a costructor like: public formAbout(int xxx){}